# How to enable Socket in PHP?

Tags: php, sockets

Could any one tell me how to enable SOCKET support in PHP ?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This answer assumes you do have a `php_sockets.dll` extension file accessible (in your PHP installation extension directory or where required);

If you're using windows, just uncomment the following line in your `php.ini` file:

```
;extension=php_sockets.dll
```

If you are missing the `php_sockets.dll`, you can download it from [php.net](http://www.php.net/downloads.php).

Comment: I have a linux godadday machine running a website. How do I enable socket programming there?

Comment: @user1051505 You might find [this discussion](http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/php-sockets/?pc_split_value=2) in the GoDaddy forums to be helpful.

Comment: I'm using XAMPP and I was getting `"Call to undefined function socket_create()..."` error. Although I have the `php_sockets.dll` file, `extension=php_sockets.dll` was not added to the `php.ini`. I had to add it manually. Now, it's working.

Comment: in xampp server , its ;extension=sockets. this helped.

Answer (score 52):

The PHP Docker images come with 3 helper script commands that make installing and configuring extensions easier:

- `docker-php-ext-configure`: This command allows you to provide the
  custom arguments for an extension.
- `docker-php-ext-install`: Use this
  command to install new extensions in your container.
- `docker-php-ext-enable`: This command can be used to enable PHP
  extensions.

**Run**

```
docker-php-ext-install sockets
```

Reference: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/php-with-bitbucket-pipelines-873907835.html#PHPwithBitbucketPipelines-InstallandenablePHPextensions

Comment: this is the correct answer if youre using docker

Comment: This showing a lot of errors. _/usr/src/php/ext/sockets/sendrecvmsg.c:128:19: error: invalid application of 'sizeof'_, _/usr/src/php/ext/sockets/sendrecvmsg.c:129:36: error: 'SCM_CREDS' undeclared_, And in the end: _make: *** [Makefile:213: sendrecvmsg.lo] Error 1_

(PHP 8.1 x64)

Answer (score 16):

here are noobs instructions

- go to your php installation directory in windows it can be something like this **c:\xampp\php**
- the go to **ext** directory in   **php\ext\**
- check if your have **php_sockets.dll** in that directory
- after that open **php.ini** file which will be in your php folder
- next search for `;extension=php_sockets.dll`

if you find it then remove `;`  from it

if you not find it then search for `extension=`

and then below some extension add  `extension=php_sockets.dll`

- and finally restart your **apache** service.

Comment: in xampp latest version you will found ;extension=sockets not this ;extension=php_sockets.dll

so you need to remove ; from ;extension=sockets and restart your apache.

Answer (score 9):

For those of you that having this problem when installing RabbitMQ php library

**Problem 1**

- Installation request for php-amqplib/php-amqplib ^2.11 -> satisfiable
  by php-     amqplib/php-amqplib[v2.11.0].
- php-amqplib/php-amqplib v2.11.0 requires ext-sockets * -> the requested PHP extension sockets is missing from your system.

**Solution**

change `;extension=sockets` to `extension=sockets` over php.init

[Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/q34fce)

**Notes:**

Not sockets.dll, only sockets

Comment: well I didn't solved my similar problem with this answer, but this answer is true and I solved it and then saw this answer. silly me :)

Comment: Hey bro, thansk for commenting yeah, lets solve more problem.

Comment: Note that it might be in a separate `.ini` file. You can list all loaded files with `php --ini`. In my case I had it in `20-sockets.ini`.

Answer (score 4):

> The socket functions described here are part of an extension to PHP which must be enabled at compile time by giving the --enable-sockets option to configure.

From the [extension's documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sockets.installation.php).