# how to install package with composer?

Tags: codeigniter, composer-php, package.json

I am trying to install a push-notification library for codeigniter using composer from[here](https://github.com/mac-cain13/notificato) .But when i do run a command it throws this error ->  Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - Installation request for wrep/notificato ^1.2 -> satisfiable by wrep/notificato[1.2.0].
    - wrep/notificato 1.2.0 requires ext-sockets * -> the requested PHP extension sockets is missing from your system.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - E:\xampp\php\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

I also did commented the php.ini extension=php_intl.dll and also its the same error occuring. How can i solve this?

[image: this]

Comment: Follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361925/how-to-enable-socket-in-php) and restart Xampp. Then repeat action with composer.

Comment: @Tpojka Thanks bro it solved my issue perfectly.

Comment: I am glad for that. Feel free to upvote that answer if was helpful.

Comment: @Tpojka Already done , Can you please up vote my question so that i can get some reputation and may this question reach to other people too. Thank you :)